# Join arrays in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, .net-3.5

What's the simplest way to join one or more arrays (or ArrayLists) in Visual Basic?

I'm using .NET 3.5, if that matters much.

Answer (score 10):

This is in C#, but surely you can figure it out...

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] b = new int[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int[] c = a.Union(b).ToArray();
```

It will be more efficient if instead of calling "ToArray" after the union, if you use the IEnumerable given instead.

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] b = new int[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
IEnumerable<int> c = a.Union(b);
```

Comment: The OP asked to join two arrays together. Not find the union which will not keep the duplicates. I do believe concat is what they might have been looking for.

Comment: You are correct.  "Join" has several meanings, but I should have understood it better.